# Blueimp adding additional call to upload file after validating file content is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, blueimp

I am using Jquery file upload blueimp. I am successfully able to upload the file. but after validating file from serverside, once I get the response back, I need to show the Upload button.Until this point it is working fine.
when the user click on upload button I have to reload the same file to server side.
This part is not working. here I am posting code.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        redirect:window.location.href.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/,'/cors/result.html?%s'),
           url:'/rest/someservice/validate',
        type:'POST',
        maxFileSize: 10000000,      
        maxNumberOfFiles:25,      
        formAcceptCharset:"utf-8",
         sequentialUploads: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(csv)$/i,
        process: [
            {
                action: 'load',
                fileTypes: /^image\/(csv)$/,
                maxFileSize: 10000000 // 10MB
            },
            {
                action: 'resize',
                maxWidth: 1440,
                maxHeight: 900
            },
            {
                action: 'save'
            }
        ]

} );



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank god!!! I am able to fix my issue. added bind event to fileuploadsend and it worked perfectly with different URL.Make sure you don't add this code inside click event.
here is the code:

```
$('#fileupload')    

    .bind('fileuploadsend', function (e, data) {
        $('#manualupload').live('click',function(){
            data.url='/rest/someservice/upload'
             data.submit();
        });

        });
```